# Knex to join tables from two databases

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I am new to Node.js. I am using Knex for querying. I need to join two tables from two different databases. Could anyone tell me how this is possible?

```
knex.select('id', 'full_name','email', 'mobile_country_code', 'mobile', knex.raw('1 as active_status')).from('users').where(whereData).union(function() {
        this.select('id','full_name', 'email', 'mobile_country_code', 'mobile', knex.raw('0 as active_status')).from('users_temp').where(whereData);
    }).then(function(data) {
        next(null, data);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        next(err.toString());
    });
```

Comment: Could you add simple case of the plain SQL query that you are trying to create?

Comment: (
SELECT u1.id, u1.full_name, u1.email, u1.mobile_country_code, u1.mobile, 1 AS active_status, u2.user_timeline_pic
FROM db1.users AS u1
JOIN db2.users AS u2 ON u1.id = u2.id
)
UNION (

SELECT id, full_name, email, mobile_country_code, mobile, 0 AS active_status,  'default/user_profile_pic.png' AS user_timeline_pic
FROM db1.users
)

Comment: What i need is given above. Thank for your reply @Mikael Lepistö

Answer (score 1):

```
knex
  .select(
    'users.id','users.full_name', 'users.email',
    'users.mobile_country_code', 'users.mobile',
    'loc.user_profile_pic', 'loc.user_timeline_pic'
  )
  .from('users')
  .leftJoin(config.project_db + '.users as loc', 'loc.id', '=', 'users.id')
  .where(whereData).union(function() {
    this.select(
      'id','full_name', 
      knex.raw('\''+constants.images.default_user_profile_pic+'\' as user_profile_pic, \''+constants.images.default_user_timleline_pic+'\' as user_timeline_pic'),
      'email', 'mobile_country_code', 'mobile'
    )
    .from('users_temp').where(whereData);
  });
```

Comment: where is this "config.project_db" coming from?
If I simple use my knex reference there it does not work

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  let data = await db1.table('table1 as t1')
    .join('table2 as t2' , 't2.idx', '=', 't1.idx')
    .first();
  res.json({ data });
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.